# Showing functions $g,h$ cannot exist

Tags: functional-analysis

So I'm doing a practice problem in my textbook where I want to show the student $t$ distribution with d.f $\nu$ cannot be a 1-dimensional exponential family.

So far in my attempt I have reduced this to showing that if it was a 1 dimensional exponential family, then for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $v> 0$ there exists functions $g,h$ such that

$$\log (1-x^2/\nu) = g(x)h(\nu)$$

I think that this must lead to a contradiction, but I'm not sure how to proceed. I was thinking that perhaps I could show this must mean $\log$ is not concave, but I haven't been able to get a contradiction in that direction.

Any ideas?

PS. Here $\log$ is natural logarithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a function $f$ of two variables satisfies
$$f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$$
for some functions of one variable $g$ and $h$, then necessarily
$h$ satisfies the identity
$$f(x_1,y_1)f(x_2,y_2)=f(x_1,y_2)f(x_2,y_1)\tag{$*$}$$
for all $x_1$, $x_2$, $y_1$, $y_2$.

In your example $f(x,y)=\ln(1-x^2/y)$. Choosing some fairly
arbitrary values for $x_1$, $x_2$, $y_1$, $y_2$ should demonstrate
that $(*)$ fails.

Comment: Thanks! Very cool way, made the proof very simple and elegant